# Check if my working is correct

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

My friend asked me for help for a question and so I tried to work it out, but I want to make sure it is correct before sending her the picture. Can anyone help?

Question: Differentiate $y = \sin x^{\cos x}.\cos x^{\sin x}$ with respect to $x$.

My solution: [image]

Comment: looks good.   You can also double-check for typos by using Wolfram-Alpha (which verifies your result). http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: In the wolfram alpha window just type d/dx  (sin(x)) ^ (cos(x))*(cos(x)) ^ (sin(x))